# integral of adapted process with respect to semimartingale is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingale, stochastic-integral

Fix $T > 0$ a finite time horizon. Let $H$ be an adapted (or progressively measurable, if needed) continuous process and S be a continuous semi martingale, both on $[0,T]$. Under what conditions is the stochastic integral $H \cdot X$ a martingale ?
For example is it enough to ask that
\begin{equation}
\Bbb{E}[\int_0^T H^2(u) du] < +\infty
\end{equation}
?

And what changes if, for example, the semimartingale S follows a geometric brownian motion ?

This question might be very simple but I am still a bit confused with all the properties of stochastic integrals and I cannot figure this out.
Thank you very much for your help.